# JPA entity field with @Convert should be `transiet` according to SonarQube

Tags: jpa, sonarqube

Given the following *simple* JPA entity,

```
@javax.persistence.Entity(name = "TRIPSTATE")
@lombok.Data
public class TripStateJpa implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String OWNERID = "OWNERID";

    @Id
    @Column(name = OWNERID)
    private Long id;


    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR2")
    @Convert(converter = TripConverter.class)
    private Trip trip;

}
```

SonarQube blames the following,

> Make "trip" transient or serializable.
> Code Smell
> Critical

The rule is **squid:S1948** and [its rule](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-1948).

`Trip` type is a POJO.
Even the field is annotated with `@Convert` does it apply anyway the rule? Won't cause any issue with JPA entity management adding the `transient` modifier?

The JPA stack in use is Spring Data JPA with Hibernate.

Comment: "Even the field is annotated with @Convert does it apply anyway the rule?" yup! :) "Won't cause any issue with JPA entity management adding the transient modifier?" it definitely will: transient and `@Column` will not work together..., solution: Make `Trip` (+descendants) *also Serializable*

Comment: ..as explained by the rule description! ;)